# Method inside another method completion wait

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, completion-block

How can I wait for some method to complete and then continue work ??

```
- (void)loadMoreDataOnBottomOfTableview
{
NSLog(@"LOADING ITEMS ON BOTTOM");
[self refreshStream];

[self.mainTableView reloadData];

...
}
```

So I need to wait refreshStream method to complete and then reload tableview data and rest of loadMoreDataOnBottomOfTableview (...).

Answer (score 1):

Use a completion block. That's what they were designed for.

See the completion handler section in this guide. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Redefine refreshStream

```
 -(void)refreshStream:(void (^)(void))complete;

 -(void)loadMoreDataOnBottomOfTableview
 {
     [self refreshStream:^{
           [self.mainTableView reloadData];
     }];
 }
```

This should do you right also check out this page, using typedef is the unspoken standard.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/BlocksGCD/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

You can call your method using this.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your query in swift. Similarly you can use completion block in your code to achieve the task.

```
class TestClosure
{

func calculateAdditionData() {

    countNumbers({ (result) -> Void in

        println("[self refreshStream] completed")
        //[self.mainTableView reloadData];
    })
}


func refreshStream(completion: (() -> Void)!) {

    //Your refresh code
    completion()
}

}
```

Completion blocks/Closures are a proper way to wait for something to complete.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` as follows:

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshStream) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]

 [self.mainTableView reloadData];
```

Note however that this is NOT a recommended design pattern.  Async calls should use callbacks (your `refreshStream` method should call back to a method in your view controller which should then trigger `reloadData`